# New language input option randomly appears on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language, input-languages

Quite consistently, but randomly, once my computer has been on for about a day or so, there appears an extra input language in the list out of nowhere.

It does not show up in the language settings. The only way to remove it is to restart the machine.

Is this a known issue? Is there a fix? How could I even investigate/debug it?

Comment: Is it always the same language? Are you using any programs that might default to a different language?

Comment: It __is__ a known issue. I have seen this one on Windows 8, 8.1, Server 2012 and 10. However, I don't know if Microsoft knows it too. So, maybe contacting them through Feedback Hub is a good idea.

Comment: @music2myear Yes, my default language is English(**UK**) [US Keyboard]. The language added is always English(**US**) [US Keyboard]. Not using anything that might mess with languages, except possibly skype. You never know with skype.; @ Fleet Command, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to replicate it on another machine I have and then report it.